# How can I declare a state and initialize it to 1 in App.js and then pull that state and increment/decrement it in another component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have App.js and epubreader.js. How can I initialize the state pageNum and set it to 1 in App.js and then pull it into the epubreader.js and set the state by incrementing or decrementing by 1? My problem right now is if I create the state pageNum in epubreader.js everytime the epubreader.js gets called, it resets the pageNum to 1. However, I want the pageNum only to be set to 1 when the application is ran.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      fullscreen: true,
      location:
        storage && storage.getItem('epub-location')
          ? storage.getItem('epub-location')
          : 2,
      localFile: null,
      localName: null,
      largeText: false,
      pageNum: 1
    }
    this.rendition = null
  }
```

```
class EBookReader extends PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.readerRef = React.createRef()
    this.state = {
      expandedToc: false,
      toc: false,
    }

    
  }
  toggleToc = () => {
    this.setState({
      expandedToc: !this.state.expandedToc
    })
  }


  next = () => {
    //Sets page num + 1
    console.log(this.state.pageNum)
      this.setState({
      pageNum: this.state.pageNum + 1

    })
    const node = this.readerRef.current
    node.nextPage()
  }

  prev = () => {
    //Sets page num - 1
        this.setState({
      pageNum: this.state.pageNum - 1

    })
    console.log(this.state.pageNum)
    const node = this.readerRef.current
    node.prevPage()
  }
```

Comment: your question isn't 100% clear, but I think you need to pass `this.state.pageNum` as a prop to `EBookReader`, assuming the latter is rendered as a child of `App`. You can also pass it down several layers, but context might be an easier solution for that.

Comment: Pass it as a prop or alternatively use a Context if prop drilling is a concern.

Comment: Sorry, I'm very new to react. Can you guys please explain how I would go about passing the state as a prop?

Comment: I can't modify props though right? Like if I passed that state in as a prop, how could I increment and decrement that value in the child component? @RobinZigmond

Comment: in that case you pass a function (or more than one) down as a prop, that will do the increment and/or decrement. See https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html